# Access and change cells in pandas dataframe based on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   'y': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                   'z': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

I'm looking for a way to access and change values in the 'z' column by indexing with the values in the x and y columns. For example, I know that the z value when x is 1 and y is 3 is 14, and I want to insert that value in at the correct location. Square bracket indexing and .loc[] weren't very helpful to me. Also, if there's a way to do this in-place without copying the dataframe every time, that would be ideal as I'm working with large datasets.

Comment: Is z a function of x and y, or is it different for every (x,y) combination?

Comment: `df.loc[df[['x','y']].eq([1,3]).all(1),'z']=14` ?

Comment: `I know that the z value when x is 1 and y is 3 is 14`, can you add this logic into the problem? What is the idea, to lookup in a list, array..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` here:

```
df['z'] = np.where((df['x']==1) & (df['y']==3), 14, df['z'])
print(df)

   x  y     z
0  1  1   NaN
1  1  2   NaN
2  1  3  14.0
3  2  1   NaN
4  2  2   NaN
5  2  3   NaN
6  3  1   NaN
7  3  2   NaN
8  3  3   NaN
```

Comment: Seems like guessing a bit though, it is unclear what op wants to set the column values with, 14 seems to only be one example

Comment: `df.loc[(df['x'] == 1) & (df['y'] == 3), 'z'] = 14` simplier I think.

Comment: This was based on his question - "For example, I know that the z value when x is 1 and y is 3 is 14, and I want to insert that value in at the correct location" that's why i added this condition